# C++ digit sum programm while loop

Tags: c++

I have recently made a program in C++ that counts a sum of digits in an input number (code below).  The program works this way.  A user is asked to input a natural number `x`. Then the program is put into a while loop which is meant to proceed until the `x` reaches 0. The `y` is a simple equation which determines the last digit of a number (i.e. `x=123`, `y=3`). `D_sum` is the sum of digits in `x` (i.e. `x=123`, `d_sum=3`).
The `x=(x-y)/10` is used to help to calculate next digit (i.e. `x=(123-3)/10=120/10=12`). The program works fine until you input a number with more than 10 digits (screen below).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x,y;
    int d_sum = 0;
    cout << "x= ";
    cin >> x;

    while(x > 0)
    {
        y=x % 10;
        d_sum++;
        x = (x - y) / 10;
    }
    cout << d_sum << endl;
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Screen:

[image: screen image]

Comment: The program does't work correctly for numbers with over 10 digits. What is the problem? How to fix it?

Comment: You can have a look at this link http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types , have a look at the range of values section

Comment: "The program works fine until you put number with more than 10 digits". The maximum amount of digits possible in a 32 bit signed int is 10, if you go over (2^31)-1 the int will overflow, yielding undefined behaviour. You could just use a type with a higher capacity i.e. `long` or even use `long long`.

Comment: Thanks. Works fine right now.

Comment: Also, If youre sure that there will not be any leading 0s and number will be positive and you wont be using this number in your program anymore after this operation, then simply use `char inp[100];` to input the number and output the `strlen(inp)`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types 
, looks like on your platform int is 32 bits. e.g. if int is 32 bit, maximum number it may be able to store would 2^31 = 2147483648.